# Are owned stocks considered balance?

Tags: interest, brokerage

I want to start investing money into stocks and for that I was comparing depots (broker bank accounts?) I found one that seemed very interesting to me but when I checked their pricing I figured that they list an negative interest on your account balance.

Now I am wondering, would I have to pay that negative interest also for money I have deposited in stocks on that account? Or is this negative interest only effective for money I have on that account without being invested into anything (being *cash*; lacking a better word)?

Comment: No one can answer this question without reading the fine print in the terms of service. One could assume that it doesn't apply to stocks, but one would be assuming instead of reading the fine print.

Comment: And how could I figure it out from that print? I mean, this is the print: https://konto.flatex.de/formularcenter_bank/public/1300100.pdf But it is in German.

Comment: I'm extremely happy that I have a free brokerage account .... In short: It seems like you're not paying 0.5% on shares that you own, it does seem like you're paying 0.1% on everything you own in your brokerage account. Regardless, is that the best you can do in Germany ? Besides trading fees I think I had better terms 20 years ago.... (Sparkasse)

Comment: @xyious: Sparkasse takes 2% of transaction value but at least 20€ per transaction. That was my first address I asked about. '^^ But yeah, from what I was trying to find, this seemed like one of the best I could find.

Comment: 0.1% per year does add up after a while.... 2% is ridiculous.... Guess you have to take what you can get and hope that something better comes along at some point